# Return Multiple Blocks in JQ With Formatting

Tags: amazon-web-services, jq, aws-cli

I have the below json as input:

```
[
    {
        "ENVIRONMENT": [
            "sit"
        ], 
        "Usage": [], 
        "id": "i-098a99bd2bd0ac86b", 
        "Name": [
            "instance1"
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "ENVIRONMENT": [
            "uat"
        ], 
        "Usage": [
            "testing"
        ], 
        "id": "i-0b210876db6d028f3", 
        "Name": [
            "instance2"
        ]
    }
]
```

I can use `jq '.[] | [.id, .ENVIRONMENT[], .Usage[], .Name[]]'` in order to get the following:

```
[
  "i-098a99bd2bd0ac86b",
  "sit",
  "instance1"
]
[
  "i-0b210876db6d028f3",
  "uat",
  "testing",
  "instance2"
]
```

Or I could use `jq '.[] | {id: .id, env: .ENVIRONMENT[], usage: .Usage[], name: .Name[]}'` to get the following (it only returns one of instances):

```
{
  "id": "i-0b210876db6d028f3",
  "env": "uat",
  "usage": "testing",
  "name": "instance2"
}
```

Is there a way I can get the second method's formatting, but return all the instances like the first method gives me? I suppose for the tag that doesn't exist in one of the instances, usage would be empty or null.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this jq filter:

```
jq '.[]|{id,env:.ENVIRONMENT[],usage:(.Usage[]//null),name:.Name[]}' file
```

which is almost the same as you, except the `.Usage[]//null` which gives the `Usage` or if not present `null`.

Note that your first attempt is the same as:

```
jq '.[]|flatten'
```

(requires jq 1.5 though)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I prefer @peak 's example below, however I appreciate the time you took to help.

I wasn't aware of the `flatten` keyword either as I use jq very rarely so thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

In general, one has to be careful about using .[] multiple times in the way that the OP has done.  If you just want the first item in each array, then you could use `.[0]` as follows:

```
.[]
| {id, env: .ENVIRONMENT[0], usage: .Usage[0], name: .Name[0]}
```

(This approach handles the case of some arrays being empty quite nicely.)

If (for example) the `.ENVIRONMENT` array might have more than one item, you might want to consider another variant such as:

```
.[]
| range(0; .ENVIRONMENT|length) as $i
| {id, env: .ENVIRONMENT[$i], usage: .Usage[$i], name: .Name[$i]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. Your first example works well for me. Can I ask though: Is the reason that my attempt didn't work because with Usage being null implicitly excluded the whole object?  
`.[] | {id: .id, env: .ENVIRONMENT[], usage: .Usage[], name: .Name[]}` **vs**
`.[] | {id, env: .ENVIRONMENT[0], usage: .Usage[0], name: .Name[0]}`  
And is that why you state one must be careful using .[] multiple times? Or is that for a different reason?

Comment: Each .[] is like a for loop, so you have to be careful how they're nested.